# Gridster - Save html content of divs to load grid dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridster

i've done some test with gridster and i can save some gridster data, like coords, size, ids etc.

But i'm unnable to save content of the divs who populate gridster in a way i can load later along with gridster coords for each element.

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
    var grid_canvas = $("#homepage > #grid").gridster({
         widget_margins: [10, 10],
         widget_base_dimensions: [140, 140],
        widget_selector: ".gs_w",
            shift_larger_widgets_down: false,
    serialize_params: function($w, wgd) {
    return {
    id: $($w).attr('id'),
    col: wgd.col, 
    row: wgd.row,
    size_x: wgd.size_x,
    size_y: wgd.size_y,

    };
    },
    draggable: {

    stop: function(event, ui) {

    var positions = JSON.stringify(this.serialize());

    $.post(
    "process.php",
    {portlets: positions},
    function(data){
        var resultado = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        $("#result").html(resultado)
            }
    );
    }
    }
            }).data('gridster');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="homepage">
      <div id="grid" style="height: 480px; position: relative; width:480px; ">
        <div id="protlet-1" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" class="gs_w"><div>Test-one</div></div>        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
```

Here my process.php:

```
<?php echo $_POST["portlets"];?>
```

I can extract all but html content of that div to recreate dynamically later.

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

when doing serialize_params,capture the html content as well. Here is a [simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/6hqzS/7/) showing the same.

```
serialize_params: function($w, wgd) 
{ 
    return { 
           id: $($w).attr('id'), 
           col: wgd.col, 
           row: wgd.row, 
           size_x: wgd.size_x, 
           size_y: wgd.size_y, 
           htmlContent : $($w).html() 
         };
}
```

When you iterate over the JSON, you will have to construct the structure. And then invoke gridster method.